# Le nom des villes étrangères en français : « New York » vs. « la Nouvelle-Orléans »

Tags: genre, toponymes

Pourquoi dit-on *New York* mais *la Nouvelle-Orléans*, et *New Jersey* mais *le Nouveau-Mexique* ? Comment sont déterminés (ou ont été fixés historiquement) les genres et la nécessité de traduction de ces toponymes ?

Comment: Question vue [sur Twitter](https://twitter.com/Maitre_Eolas/status/263248344174981121)

Comment: Parce que seuls *Orleans* et *Mexico* ont des équivalents français ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez non, contre-exemple: la Nouvelle-Amsterdam

Comment: Peut-être que mélanger trois langues différentes ça faisait trop :-)

Comment: Raisons historiques? Pendant longtemps la Louisiane faisait partie du Royaume de France, et la Nouvelle-Orléans avait donc originellement un nom en français... Pour le Nouveau-Mexique, aucune idée...

Comment: Et que dire de _Los Angeles_, _San Franscisco_ ou _Bâton Rouge_ dont le nom n'est même pas traduit dans la langue du pays ?

Answer (score 8):

Le procédé d'utiliser un nom différent de celui d'origine s'appelle *exonymie* [<sup>wikipédia</sup>](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exonymie).

Comme le souligne Thierry Grass <sup>1</sup> (et Romain VALERI dans [sa réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/3345/991)), il n'existe pas nécessairement de règles et l'on pourra donner des explications historiques ou sociales, au cas par cas.

> Ces exonymes ont été intégrés dans notre langue selon  divers
>   processus qui en ont fait un ensemble extrêmement hétérogène et sans
>   logique  interne ; ainsi, à partir d’un nom unique russe Москва translittéré
>   *Moskva*, a-t-on en français  deux noms différents, *Moscou* pour la
>   capitale de la Russie et *Moskova* pour le fleuve qui y coule.

Dans ce même papier sont présentés 4 cas d'utilisation de toponymes étrangers :

- inchangé, emprunt
- translittéré : changement d'alphabet (normalisé, et réversible)
- transcrit : adaptation dans la langue locale
- traduit

À noter que le Groupe d’experts des Nations Unies pour les noms géographiques (GENUNG) préconise l'utilisation de la nomenclature officielle des pays s'ils utilisent l'alphabet latin et le cas échéant la translitération.

---

<sup>1</sup> *La traduction comme appropriation : le cas des toponymes étrangers*, Thierry Grass, [DOI: 10.7202/014333ar](http://dx.doi.org/10.7202/014333ar).

Comment: Et pour compliquer les choses, il y a les langues utilisant des extensions de l'alphabet latin — accents, lettres supplémentaires ­— et parfois plusieurs systèmes de translittération concurrents.

Answer (score 6):

Ce sont des noms propres, donc par définition ils sont arbitraires. Je ne vois pas bien ce qui empêcherait une ville (dans la mesure où ce serait le choix assumé de ses habitants) de s'appeler même "La New Stuttgart" ou "Die Nouvelle London" ...

Il me semble que tu cherches des règles logiques hors de leur domaine d'application...

Cela dit, la plupart du temps (comme évoqué en commentaires), ceux qui ont fait ces choix ont opté pour un qualificatif (nouvelle/new) lié à la langue d'origine de la ville dont ils empruntaient le nom, c'est-à-dire dans l'immense majorité des cas, à leur propre langue. (Je veux dire par exemple, il y a fort à parier que les fondateurs de "La Nouvelle Orléans" étaient francophones, et même originaires/nostalgiques d'Orléans...)

Je ne vois pas d'autre réponse globale à ta question. En revanche, on pourra bien sûr, pour chacune de ces villes, retrouver les raisons plus ou moins explicites dans leurs archives, mais seulement au cas par cas.

Comment: Ce ne sont pas les habitants de New York qui ont décidé que la ville s'appellerait *New york* en français et pas *Nouvelle York* (cf. l'espagnol Nueva York).