# Pourquoi la plupart des états américains sont masculins hormis quelques exceptions?

Tags: genre, noms-propres, toponymes

Il y a 9 états américains qui sont féminins mais les autres sont masculins.  Quel serait la règle pour connaître le genre des états pour un non francophone?

---

9 American states' nouns are feminine but the others are masculine.  What's the rule to know the gender of the states' nouns for a non-francophone?

Comment: Cinq de ces états portent des noms de femme : les deux Carolines, les deux Virginies et la Géorgie (Georgia, féminin de George)... pour les autres, je ne sais pas vraiment. Mais ces trucs de genres habituellement, ça s'apprend plus que ça se comprend.

Comment: @Kareen: faux pour la Georgie qui doit son nom au Roi d'Angleterre de l'époque où l'état a été fondé.

Comment: @air-dex Oui pour le roi George, mais reste que *Georgia* est la forme féminine de George, même en anglais, et ça aide à se rappeler que cet état est féminin, peu importe d'où vient le nom exactement. L'étymologie des Virginies est *country of the virgin*, nommées ainsi pour la Reine Élizabeth I, *the Virgin Queen*, mais Virginie, c'est aussi un nom de femme.

Comment: @air-dex De plus, les Carolines, étymologiquement, sont nommées après le roi Charles, du francique « karl ». Bref, je ne parlais pas de l'étymologie du nom des états, qui est d'ailleurs probablement la même que celle des prénoms.

Comment: Question reliée à celle-ci : *[Le nom des villes étrangères en français : « New York » vs. « la Nouvelle-Orléans »](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/3343/19)*

Comment: J'assume que c'est la terminaison féminine -a qui a une influence sur le genre féminin: en anglais les noms sont Georgia, Florida, Carolina, California.

Comment: @rogermue Pas nécessairement. On peut penser aux deux Dakotas, à l'Alaska, à l'Arizona, au Nevada, et j'en passe.

Comment: Tu peut avoir raison. Je n'ai pas étudié ce problème à fond, c'est pourquoi j'ai écrit "j'assume". Mais je pense qu'on dit en anglais California? Yes, it is a beautiful country et pas She is a beautiful country. Ainsi il faudrait modifier la question. Ces états ont une terminaison féminine, mais ils n'ont pas le genre féminin.

Comment: @rogermue Il n'y a pas de « neutre » en français. Les mots sont soit féminins, soit masculins. La question est tout à fait correcte en demandant pourquoi 9 états (sous-entendu les *noms* de ces états) sont féminins.

Comment: Tu as raison. Je suis trop souvent sur le forum anglais.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kareen note un point concernant les Carolines. La Louisiane et la Floride datent probablement d'avant l'entrée de ces états dans l'Union: la Louisiane fut colonie française, la Floride était Espagnole (cf. *la Barbade*, Angl. *Barbados*). Quant aux autres exceptions (Californie, les Virginies, Georgie, Pennsylvanie), c'est tout simplement la règle que les noms en -ie sont féminins!

Quand aux états masculins, je crois que le défaut pour la vaste majorité des noms propres étrangers sans tradition française est le genre de leurs génériques. Les états américains et les provinces canadiennes sont d'ailleurs un cas un peu particulier: dans le cas du Mexique ou du Brésil, on dit en français *l'état de*, par ex. *l'état d'Oaxaca*, jamais *l'Oaxaca* (du moins je n'ai jamais rencontré cette formulation dans les médias).

---

Kareen notes a point concerning the Carolinas.  *La Louisiane* and *la Floride* probably date from before the entry of these states into the Union: Louisiana was a French colony, Florida was Spanish (cf. *la Barbade* - Barbados).  As for the other exceptions (California, the Virginias, Georgia, Pennsylvania), the rule is simply that the *-ie* at the end of their French names makes them feminine!

For the states with masculine nouns, I think that the default for the vast majority of proper foreign names without a French tradition is to use the gender of their [generic noun](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nom_propre#Nom_propre_et_genre).  The American states and Canadian provinces are, on the other hand, a slightly odd case: in the case of Mexico or Brazil, the French say *l'état de*; for example, *l'état d'Oaxaca*, never *l'Oaxaca* (at least I've never come across this phrasing in the media).

Comment: « le genre de leur génériques » ?

Comment: La *rivière* Saint-Charles, le *fleuve* Saint-Laurents, le *mont* Saint-Hilaire, les *collines* Montérégiennes. C'est un terme qu'on rencontre très communément dans les guides d'usages francophones canadiens (une nominalisation de [*nom générique*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nom_propre#Nom_propre_et_genre)).

Answer (score 2):

Les règles s'appellent pifomètre, euphonie et feeling de celui qui le prononce.

La réponse à cette question est la même que pour la question "pourquoi certains noms sont féminins et d'autres masculins ?". Un humoriste français avait même fait un sketch dessus (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HHd9vCVYvFM).

---

The rules are called *pifomètre*, rules of thumb, euphony, and the feeling of the one who's speaking.

The answer to this question is the same as for the question, "why are certain nouns feminine and others masculine?"  A French comedian even made a sketch on it (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HHd9vCVYvFM).

Answer (score 1):

Il y a toujours des exceptions en français mais en général, les mots appartenant à un champ lexical défini sont de même genre.

On dit « un état », donc la plupart des états sont masculins. Pour ce qui est des états féminins, c'est différent car il s'agit de prénoms féminins, d’où l'exception à la règle.

Voici un autre exemple : le mot « console » est féminin ; « une console ». Par conséquent, on dit une « gameboy », une « sega », une « nintendo », etc.

Comment: Autre exemple : les voitures et camionnettes sont féminines, mais les breaks et les utilitaires sont masculins… [sauf qu'il semblerait que le masculin s'étende ces dernières années](http://transports.blog.lemonde.fr/2014/10/15/mon-mecedes-le-ds-comment-la-voiture-change-de-genre/). Cela dit, ta réponse fait un peu doublon avec celle de Circeus.

Answer (score 0):

Peut-être par chance, il paraît que les états aux noms féminins sont tous ceux où il y a une différence entre le nom français et le nom anglais, à la seule exception du Nouveau-Mexique (ce qui est logique, puisque le Mexique est masculin en français).

---

Perhaps by chance, it seems that the states with feminine nouns are all those where there's a difference between the French and English name, the sole exception being New Mexico (which is logical, since *Mexico* is masculine in French).

Comment: On dit *le* Dakota du Sud.